# How to make "symbol" typeface italic in illustrator?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I want to type $Omega$ $\omega$ (in Latex) as italic in Illustrator. I found that there are such fonts under "symbol" typeface but there is only "Medium" setting instead of "italic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a typeface with an italic version and use that. That sounds blunt, but it's a harsh truth: Illustrator will not make a font italic by itself, it requires a separate font file with the italic version. This is good: the 'italicise' function that lots of word processors use, is nothing but a 'slant' function that does not produce passable italics for a lot of typefaces.

If you **really** need to simulate italic by slanting type, you can use <kbd>Object > Transform > Shear</kbd>.